# python: list of lists of matching dicts

Tags: python

I have a few dicts like:

`a = [ { 'event_id': 1}, { 'event_id': 1}, { 'event_id': 1}, { 'event_id': 2}, { 'event_id': 2}, { 'event_id': 3} ]`

I want a list of lists, each sublist containing all the dicts with similar `event_id` values:

`[ [ { 'event_id': 1}, { 'event_id': 1}, { 'event_id': 1} ], [ { 'event_id': 2}, { 'event_id': 2} ], [ { 'event_id': 3} ] ]`

Is there a quick recipe for this?

Comment: So the dicts only have that one key `'event_id'`? And what does "similar" `event_id` values mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [amadan suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39823731/1843865), `itertools.groupby` is a great approach to this problem. It takes an iterable and a key function to group by. You'll first want to make sure your list is sorted by the same key so that groupby doesn't end up creating multiple groups for the same key (similar to how you do an ORDER BY before a GROUP BY in SQL).

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

grouping_key = itemgetter('event_id')  # produces a function like lambda x: x['event_id']

# If your events weren't already ordered with adjacent 'event_id's:
ordered_a = sorted(a, key=grouping_key)

grouped_a = [list(group) for _grouper, group in groupby(ordered_a, key=grouping_key)]
```

Answer (score 2):

`itertools.groupby` is perfect for this:

```
map(lambda x: list(x[1]), (itertools.groupby(a, lambda x: x['event_id'])))
# => [[{'event_id': 1}, {'event_id': 1}, {'event_id': 1}], [{'event_id': 2}, {'event_id': 2}], [{'event_id': 3}]]
```

EDIT: As Justin Turner Arthur says in comments, this is not great (mostly because I completely forgot that Python groups only adjacent elements). Please use his solution.

Comment: I like where this one is going, though you'll want to ensure the list is sorted by the grouping key before you group it.
    `event_key = itemgetter('event_id')`
    `ordered_a = sorted(a, key=event_key)`

You can also make it a bit more pythonic by replacing the map with a list comprehension:

    `[list(group) for grouper, group in (itertools.groupby(ordered_a, event_key))]`

Comment: @JustinTurnerArthur: You are completely right. I am more used to Ruby, and Python requires more hoop-jumping. If you submit that as your solution, you have my vote.

Answer (score 0):

First, make a dictionary mapping `event_id` values to lists of dicts.

```
d = {}
for dict_ in a:
    if dict_['event_id'] in d:
        d[dict_['event_id']].append(dict_)
    else:
        d[dict['event_id']] = [dict_]
```

Then make a list comprehension to gather them all into one list:

```
[val for key , val in d.items()]
```